# How to change img margin inside a table using css hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I want slightly move the image on mouse over, but it doesn't work.
Images are inside a table cell. Cells have no spacing, no padding, no defined height
Images outside the table - work well.

```css
#img01 { 
    width:25px; 
    height:25px; 
    margin:9px 10px 0px 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#img01:hover {
    margin-top:4px;
}
```

Comment: This CSS seems correct to me. What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are inline by default. Try adding:

```
display: block
```

to the images.

Comment: I made them now display:block, but now they are stacked vertically inside a cell, instead horizontally

Comment: Try floating them left and giving them a width

Comment: I'm afraid a will loose space between them, but i will try. Just a minute

Comment: Try floating them left and make the width the actual width of the item or image and add a right margin to them.

Comment: make them `inline-block` and avoid all the floating